# How to merge two csv files line by line

Tags: python, csv

I'm using python 3.0 in windows.

i have 2 csv files

file1.csv

```
0, 10,12
0,11,12
1,15,12
2, 17,12
```

file2.csv

```
0, 2, 1
1,22, 1
3, 11, 1
```

output.csv

```
0, 10,12
0,11,12
0, 2, 1
1,15,12
1,22, 1
2, 17,12
3, 11, 1
```

i tried the following code

```
a = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
b = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
c = pd.concat([a, b], join='outer')
c.to_csv("Output.csv", index = False)
```

But my output is

```
0, 10,12
0,11,12
1,15,12
2, 17,12
0, 2, 1
1,22, 1
3, 11, 1
```

Can you give me some pointers please. I'm new to python.

Comment: What's the logic? How should the lines be sorted?

Comment: So you want to put them side by side? I'd read with `<left or right>_array = np.genfromtxt('input_filename.csv', delimiter=',')`, put them side by side with `out = np.hstack([left_array, right_array])` and then write the file with `np.savetxt('output_filename.csv', out, delimiter=',')`.

Comment: You can also specify a format in `savetxt`, see the docs. Note that this can only work if both inputs have same number of lines which is not the case in your examplary data. Please specify more clearly what you are trying to do (present the idea as well as given input and expected output).

Comment: Is your output correct?  It almost looks like you want to interleave these two files, but it's not clear why the pattern between files is 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate and sort them with pandas:

```
df = pd.concat([a, b]).astype('str')

df = df.sort_values(list(df.columns))

df.to_csv('Output.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not create the output file but it demonstrates how [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) could help:

```
from heapq import merge
inputs = [file(f) for f in ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv']]
for line in merge(*inputs):
    print line,
```

With the sample data this produces

```
0, 10,12
0, 2, 1
0,11,12
1,15,12
1,22, 1
2, 17,12
3, 11, 1
```

However this differs from the sample output in the ordering of the initial lines:

```
0, 10,12
0,11,12
0, 2, 1
```

but I'm not sure how to produce this ordering.  The sample output lines do not appear to be ordered by character or numeric columns (a numeric ordering of the fields would presumably put `0, 2, 1` first).

EDIT: it appears the lines are ordered as if spaces were not present.  The following example:

```
from heapq import merge
def reader(f):
    for line in file(f):
        yield line.replace(' ',''), line
inputs = [reader(f) for f in ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv']]
for pair in merge(*inputs):
    print pair[1],
```

generates this ordering:

```
0, 10,12
0,11,12
0, 2, 1
1,15,12
1,22, 1
2, 17,12
3, 11, 1
```